# Javascript - cache input text?

Tags: javascript, caching, input

I have a question about javascript caching?

Is there any way to save input from keyboard to any object/element or whatelse in which I can store user input from keyboard when focus is not on the textbox?

And after I focused od textbox, then I want to typed text is automatically put to textbox?

I need this, for example, if in one textbox exist function which executes for about 1-2 sec, and if I quick select another textbox and instantly start typing, then a first few characters will now typed in the second textbox, because the function in first textbox is still executing...

Which approach is the best for this case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is solvable quite easy using jQuery I think. You can try do some experiments with the following snippet, which should do exactly what you want:

```js
jQuery(function() {
    var inputBuffer = "";
    
    jQuery("body").keypress(function(event) {
        // Collect input that is not being processed by an input/textarea field
        inputBuffer += String.fromCharCode(event.charCode);
    });
    jQuery("input,textarea").focus(function(event) {
        // Append buffered input to text field
        jQuery(this).val( jQuery(this).val() + inputBuffer );
        // Clear buffer
        inputBuffer = "";
    });
    jQuery("input,textarea").blur(function(event) {
        // Discard input buffer
        // Prevent from using input collected while having an input/textarea in focus
        inputBuffer = "";
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <p>Some non-input element</p>
</div>
<input type="text" />
```

Comment: yes, this is it! But, does exists any approach using only javascript without any external library? Do you have any idea?

Comment: if you want to support older versions of Internet Explorer this would result in a much more complicated script. if not you could replace the jQuery event handlers by a combination of Document/Element.querySelector and regular javascript events. For examples/documentation see: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector / https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector / http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp